# Passing FUNC<> to my jsonResponseObj class in MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, json.net, func

I'm using a lot of Json.NET in my MVC4 site and I tried to simplify things a bit by using FUNC in my JsonNetResult class.  I found that when I was writing a JsonNetResult controller action, I was wrapping everything in the same try/catch statement, so I made a method in the JsonNetResult class that takes a Func as an input.  However, I've found that object as an input doesn't work - I have to be specific and I've eneded up just making a bunch of overload methods that take different types as the argument in the `Func<>`.

Is there a way to use an object as an input in this case?  Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do?  I'm trying to adhere to DRY, but I can't figure out how to leverage the FUNC<> to do that correctly.  I appreciate any help or pointers.

code from controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public JsonNetResult jsonUpdateProfile(UserProfile u)
    {
        JsonNetResult j = new JsonNetResult();
        var x = ModelState;
        Func<UserProfile, jsonResponseObj> updater = p => updateUserProfile(p);
        j.GetResponseObj(updater, u);

        return j;
    }

    private jsonResponseObj updateUserProfile(UserProfile u)
    {   
        UserProfile updateUser = db.UserProfiles.Find(u.UserId);
        updateUser = u;
        updateUser.UpdatedBy = u.UserName;
        updateUser.UpdatedOn = DateTime.Now;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return new jsonResponseObj(null,"Profile Updated");
    }
```

code from JsonNetResult : ActionResult

```
public void GetResponseObj(Func<object, jsonResponseObj> custom, object arg)
{
    try
    {
        Data = custom.Invoke(arg);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // alert elmah
        Data = new jsonResponseObj(ex);
    }
}
```

this `jsonResponseObj` class is just a wrapper for my JSON data to standardize all responses:

```
public class jsonResponseObj
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public Object data { get; set; }
    public string msg { get; set; }

    public jsonResponseObj(Object data, string msg = "")
    {
        this.status = "OK";
        this.data = data;
        this.msg = msg;
    }

    public jsonResponseObj(Exception ex)
    {
        this.status = "ERROR";
        this.msg = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your `GetResponseObj` method to be generic:

```
    public void GetResponseObj<T>(Func<T, jsonResponseObj> custom, T arg) where T:class
    {
        try
        {
            Data = custom(arg);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // alert elmah
            Data = new jsonResponseObj(ex);
        }
    }
```

But maybe it will be better solution to add `ActionFilter` to catch your exceptions:

```
public class ExceptionToJsonNetResultAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.ExceptionHandled)
            return;

        if (!filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            return;

        if (filterContext.Result is JsonNetResult)
            return;

        ProcessException(filterContext);
    }

    private static void ProcessException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 500;
        filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
        filterContext.Result = new JsonResult
        {
            Data = new jsonResponseObj(filterContext.Exception);                
        };
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
    }
}
```

Now you can decorate your actions with this attribute and throw your try/catch block off.

Comment: Also, @Kirill Bestemyanov - where is the _errorHandlingService property declared?  I also don't see that as an arg in the ProcessException method.  Should this implement IActionFilter?

Comment: it is not needed. You should remove it from statement. I update answer.